# Android application not working on hdpi density?

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am working on an android application. I have created a layout for 320*480 size screen. My layout showa properly for MDPI and LDPI, but not on HDPI screens. What may be the reason for this and how can I sort it out?

Comment: how is it not working?crash or layout problems?

Comment: in this case follow @Nirali exhaustive checklist, also use adt layout builder, it helps understanding how android chooses the right resources for different devices at runtime

Answer (score 3):

- Use Density-independent Pixels
- Provide Alternative Bitmaps

Read this doc
[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

- Use "wrap_content" and "match_parent"
- Use RelativeLayout
- Use Size Qualifiers
- Use the Smallest-width Qualifier
- Use Layout Aliases
- Use Orientation Qualifiers
- Use Nine-patch Bitmaps

Refer to this doc  [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)